# Applescript GUI on Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, pdf-generation, applescript, osx-mountain-lion

I am trying to make a script that opens an swf file with safari and then print it as a pdf using the built in "Save as PDF" feature. So far my code looks like this:

```
set appleworksFolder to choose folder

tell application "Finder"
set folderItems to (files of entire contents of appleworksFolder)
repeat with I from 1 to number of items in folderItems
    set the_doc to item I of folderItems
    set doc_name to name of the_doc as text
    tell application "Finder"
        set the clipboard to doc_name & ".pdf"
    end tell
    if name of the_doc is not ".DS_Store" then
        try
            tell application "Safari"
            activate
                open the_doc
                tell application "System Events"
                    tell application process "Safari"
                        delay 1
                        click menu item "Print…" of menu "File" of menu bar 1
                        delay 5
                        click menu button "PDF" of window "Print" of application process "Safari" of application "System Events"
                        delay 1
                        click menu item "Save as PDF…" of menu "PDF" of menu button "PDF" of window "Print" of application process "Safari" of application "System Events"
                        delay 1
                        keystroke "v" using command down
                        click button "Save" of window "Save" of application process "Safari" of application "System Events"
                        delay 8
                        keystroke "w" using command down
                        delay 0.5
                    end tell
                end tell
            end tell
        end try
    end if
end repeat
end tell
```

This works up to seeing the print dialogue, but it doesn't seem to click the pdf menu button so doesn't get any further than this. I was wondering if this is a problem with mountain lion not letting me use applescript to control buttons, and if so, is there a fix for it? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could also try using [wkpdf](http://plessl.github.com/wkpdf/) to create the PDFs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just showed someone how to do this in Mail on another website. You can see that in post #7 [here](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=39881). Anyway, here's that code adjusted for your particulars and Safari. I hope it helps!

```
set appleworksFolder to choose folder

tell application "Finder"
    set folderItems to (files of entire contents of appleworksFolder) as alias list
end tell

repeat with i from 1 to count of folderItems
    set thisItem to (item i of folderItems) as text

    tell application "Finder"
        set n to name of file thisItem
        set c to (container of file thisItem) as text
    end tell

    tell application "Safari"
        activate
        open file thisItem
    end tell

    saveAsPDFInSafari(c, n, true)
end repeat

tell me
    activate
    display dialog "Finished!" buttons {"OK"} default button 1 with icon note
end tell

(*********** SUBROUTINES *************)
on saveAsPDFInSafari(saveFolder, saveFileName, shouldCloseWhenFinished)
    set myDelay to 0.2

    -- setup the name
    if saveFileName does not end with ".pdf" then
        if character -4 of saveFileName is "." then
            set saveFileName to text 1 thru -5 of saveFileName
        end if
        set saveFileName to saveFileName & ".pdf"
    end if

    -- setup the folder
    set saveFolder to saveFolder as text
    set posixSaveFolder to POSIX path of saveFolder
    if posixSaveFolder ends with "/" then set posixSaveFolder to text 1 thru -2 of posixSaveFolder

    -- save as pdf
    tell application "Safari" to activate
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Safari"
            keystroke "p" using command down
            repeat until exists sheet 1 of window 1
                delay myDelay
            end repeat

            tell sheet 1 of window 1
                click menu button "PDF"
                repeat until exists menu 1 of menu button "PDF"
                    delay myDelay
                end repeat

                click menu item "Save as PDF…" of menu 1 of menu button "PDF"

            end tell

            repeat until exists (sheet 1 of sheet 1 of window 1)
                delay myDelay
            end repeat

            keystroke saveFileName
            delay myDelay

            keystroke "g" using {command down, shift down}
            repeat until exists sheet 1 of sheet 1 of sheet 1 of window 1
                delay myDelay
            end repeat

            tell sheet 1 of sheet 1 of sheet 1 of window 1
                set value of text field 1 to posixSaveFolder
                delay myDelay
                click button "Go"
            end tell

            repeat while exists sheet 1 of sheet 1 of sheet 1 of window 1
                delay myDelay
            end repeat

            tell sheet 1 of sheet 1 of window 1
                click button "Save"
            end tell

            repeat while exists sheet 1 of sheet 1 of window 1
                delay myDelay
            end repeat

            repeat while exists sheet 1 of window 1
                delay myDelay
            end repeat

            if shouldCloseWhenFinished then
                keystroke "w" using command down
            end if
        end tell
    end tell
end saveAsPDFInSafari
```